# Created concrete material by following a 2.79 tutorial in 2.8 and messed up true displacement

Tags: materials, node-editor

Here's the tutorial I followed:

https://youtu.be/wmtAVNDtc_w

The only change I made was i skipped a portion with the image texture around 5:30 because i didn't find any major change without it and he youtuber didn't provide any link for the image. So now I'm left with a mesh that ignores true displacement in eevee and takes it too far in cycles

here are some screens links as the page isnt allowing me to upload them directly:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/FPrTejKkSQqiCWVdA

And here is the blender file:
[image]

Comment: What's your question? You haven't asked anything. Be specific if you wish a specific answer.

Comment: I want to fix the messed up mesh that I'm left with, check out those screens to understand the situation

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You can post images so they are shown with your question so people can see them straight away instead of clicking on a link. If you make it hard for people to help you, there is less chance for you to get the help you wish to get. It's best to follow the format of the platform as much as possible. You should also describe what you think is wrong in the images, what the desired results are and how the results you get differ from them.

Comment: i understand that sir, but for some reason the page doesn't respond to submit whenever i try to upload one directly

Answer (score 3):

Due to adding vector displacement not so long ago to Blender you have to use dedicated displacement node to convert scalar to vector displacement.

[image]

I would say that your shader structure is outdated. It is better to mix RGBs instead of shaders, and use Principled BSDF instead of mixing Diffuse and Glossy. Take a look at the blend file. Although this is not the best example to demonstrate the superiority of the approach, I changed it so it would reflect the idea without altering the artistic component. The shader became heavier but more realistic and PBR.

[image]
[image]

[image]